# How to create an npm script

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I have two folders: client and server. When I run the server, I want to create a distribution command with the npm run build command in the client folder.

For example, what I want to do is to run npm start in the server folder and then run npm run build in the client folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use the library called [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) where you will be able to run multiple commands from one run script. In your `package.json` add some scripts like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start-dev": "node index.js",
    "client-build": "npm build --prefix ../client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-dev\" \"npm run client-build\""
  }
```

Then you will just need to run the script `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

This bash script will run the server in a background process, then change into the client directory and build it.

```sh
cd server
npm run start &
cd ../client
npm run build
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can understand what it does and learn from it?